# Specifying resolution for objects with known dimensions using CNN

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I would like to ask you for advice. I deal with beekeeping but I am also a bit a programmer and an electronics specialist. And this is where my 3 interests come together, actually 4 because recently deep learning has joined this group.
I would like to analyze (I already run some tests) bee behavior using deep learning mechanisms based on images (photos or videos) with bees. These images, of course, can be very different, this applies primarily to the area that can be shown. It can literally be 2x3cm like a macro picture or an area of ​​40x30cm and 3000 bees on it. Trying to create a network analyzing such different areas is a nightmare. And because I am interested in aspects of bees separately, it seems logical to divide the image into these parts, which will contain single bees in their entirety, reduce their resolution to a minimum ensuring recognition of the necessary details and only then analyze each part of the large image separately.
This approach seems even more right to me when I started to read the details, e.g. YOLOv3. Thanks to this, I would avoid a large amount of additional calculations.

And here comes the first stage to be implemented. I need to specify the image resolution, more precisely the number of pixels that on average falls on one bee length. If it is too small, I do nothing but say that the resolution is too small for analysis. If it is suitable (at least 50 pixels for the length of the bee), I algorithmically cut the input image into smaller ones so that they contain individual insects and I subject them to further analysis.

Fortunately, the sizes of bees and bee cells are precisely known to within 0.1mm. And there may be hundreds of such objects (a bee or a hexagonal bee cell) and I can decide how many of them will be at the stage of preparing training data. I have thousands of photos and videos from which I can easily create training data for the network in the form of pairs of objects image bee size expressed in pixels from this image.

Time for question:
At the output I want to get a number saying that one bee in the image is X pixels long, e.g. 43.02 or 212.11
Has anyone of you dealt with a similar case of determining resolution for known objects using a neural network (probably CNN with an output element with rel function) and can share your experience, e.g. a network structure that would be suitable for this purpose?